# React json rendering cat images

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I cant seem to get my react project to work. I am trying to create a application that will display random cat images, I have included the code and the api link here https://aws.random.cat/meow

If anyone can help me figure out how to get this to work, I would really apprectiate it, I think my problem is in my map function. I am new to using React and am trying to learn more. Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ICS 211 - React</title>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
   
   class Application extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
     //super is calling the constructor from react component
     super(props);
     //seting the state
     this.state = { cats: [] };
    };
    //we want to fetch the api and take the value it returns and set it equal to data
    componentDidMount() {
     (async () => {
      try {
       //change
       const response = await fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow');
       if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
       const data = await response.json();
       //change
       this.setState({ cats: data });
      }catch(error){
       console.log('Fetch API Error: ' + error);
      }
     }) ();
    }
    
    render() {
     return (
      <div>
      
      <StyledTitle />
       <ol>
        {this.state.cats.map(cat => <StyledApplication key={cat.file}/>)}
       </ol>
      </div>
     );
    }
   }
 
   
  
   //structure and style for the Title object
   const Title = ({ className }) => (
    <div className={className}>
     <h1>random cats</h1>
    
    </div>
   );

   const StyledApplication = styled(Application)`
   background-color: white;
   padding: 15px;
   color: lightgreen;`;

   const StyledTitle = styled(Title)`
   font-size: 45pt;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   color: #6699ff;
   padding: 3%;
   border: solid green 2px;
   background: lightgreen;`;
   
 
   
   //structure and style for the Movie object
   // link,name,checked is the json object
   const struct = ({ className, file }) => {

     return <li className={className}>{className}: <a href={file}>{file}</a></li>
   
   };
   



   ReactDOM.render(
    <Application/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
   );
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't map over an object.

Comment: Ohhh... okay so what can I do instead? how can I make this functional

Comment: You should push the link to an array in your state, and then map over the array instead.

Comment: Can you show me how you would fix it? got a exam tomorrow, and took way to many classes. this is 80% of my exam, being able to render json using react. I gotta nail this down tonight

Comment: Try using `this.setState({ cats: [...this.state.cats,  data] })`. It would be better to just push the link, though, not an object, i.e. `this.setState({ cats: [...this.state.cats,  data.file] })`. You would have to change your other component to fix this

Comment: Thanks, ill try it out but im having a hard time. Just want to see what a working version would look like, so i can see the mistakes more clearly. I am more of a visual learner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips that can solve your problem

1. **USE SPREAD OPERATOR TO PUSH ELEMENTS TO THE CATS ARRAY**

You have initialized cats as an array and in order to push the data returned in response use spread operator like this

`this.setState({ cats: [...data] });`

2. **RETURN KEYWORD IS MISSING IN MAP FUNCTION**

You have to specify what is returning from map function like this

`{this.state.cats.map(cat => return <StyledApplication key={cat.file}/>)}`

moreover, if you check the iterator you have passed in map function is `cats`
but in prop `key` you are passing `cat.item` you need to correct that as well like i did above.

3. **USE AXIOS (optional)**

In order to make network requests make use of [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) package. Axios makes it easy to send asynchronous HTTP requests to REST endpoints

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The API returned an object and map function is for array. You should do something like this:

```
state = {
    cat: null
}

render() {
    const { cat }= this.state;
    return (
        <div>
             <StyledApplication key={cat.file}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If you want an array of object, do the following

```
state = {
    cats: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    ...
    const { cats } = this.state;
    // Clone the array because of immutability 
    const copy = cats.map(c => {...c});
    copy.push(data);
    this.setState({ cats: copy });
    ...
}

render() {
    const { cat }= this.state;
    return (
        <div>
             <StyledApplication key={cat.file}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It does not work because key is a reserved props and you should not use key as a props for StyledApplication. Also it would be best if you tell me how it doesn't work instead of staying it doesn' work

Comment: check my changes to the code , not iterating over the cats array instead using cat

Comment: You changed this.state.cats(cats => ... ) to this.state.cats(cat => ... ). But this is still iterating over the array.
this.state.cats is an array.
state = {
    cats: []
} is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing that's correct but your api response is an object what I can see. And you are trying to loop through that object. Hence it's not working. Either change the api response or format the api response data and make it an array.

Comment: Thanks, ill try it out but im having a hard time. Just want to see what a working version would look like, so i can see the mistakes more clearly. I am more of a visual learner